# "Is there a plane" or "Do you have a flight", which is better?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Assuming I'm speaking to staff at a booking center, which of these is better?

> Is there a plane to London today?

or

> Do you have a flight to London today?

And why?

Comment: Can you clarify your audience? Are you speaking to an airline rep, a friend, etc?

Comment: Yes, soeaking with staff at a flight booking counter.

Answer (score 2):

I would say "do you have a flight to London" or "is there a plane **going** to London".

I can't say why beyond my intuition as a native AmE speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Both will work fine and are used regularly by fluent speakers of English.  However using "flight" is slightly better.  "Is there a plane to London today?" is really a shortened version of "Is there a plane that will be going to London today?"

"Is there a flight to London today?" could be better than "Do you have a flight to London today?" because the former allows the the staff to tell you about fights that other airlines have even if the staff member's airline does not have the flight you are looking for.

"Do you have a flight to London today?"   "No we do not."

"Is there a flight to London today?"  "Yes.  We don't have one, but Lufthansa does."